# How to get module name by file name?

Tags: perl

I have module `Foo::Bar::Baz`, which is located on `/some_path/Foo/Bar/Baz.pm`, and perl script that runs from `/some_path/Foo/Bar`. Script need to analyse all modules in this folder.

How can I get module name (`Foo::Bar::Baz`) by file name (`Baz.pm`) ? I can't just trim `.pm` ending and also `lib` path in @INC is non-deterministic

Firstly I supposed to use [new_from_file](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Info#name) and [name](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Info#name) methods of [Module::Info](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Info), but unfortunately

> Module loaded using new_from_file() won't have this information

Looks like I need some module which do static code analysis. Anyone knows its name ?

Comment: Any chance you could provide a more detailed explanation on what you're trying to do or expect as output? I'm almost positive my [Devel::Examine::Subs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Examine::Subs) can do what you require, but it's been a while, and I'd need further clarification for testing (I use [PPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) in the background).

Comment: You are assuming that there *is* a (single, unique) module name. That's not necessarily the case. What do you want to do if there are 0 or 2+ names?

Comment: Change your script so it takes two inputs: The base dir (`/some_path`) and a package name (`Foo::Bar::Baz`, or maybe even `Foo::Bar::*`)

Comment: Thanks all for answers, finally I used [Module::Metadata](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Metadata) for my [project](https://metacpan.org/release/App-iperlmoddir).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no requirement for package names to match the filename it was loaded from to begin with, or [for the first package to](https://metacpan.org/source/JPEACOCK/version-0.9924/vperl/vpp.pm). But for any sanely-written module that you can `use` normally and even some weird ones, [Module::Metadata](https://perldoc.pl/Module::Metadata) can find this information. As a general rule, you should work with absolute filenames regardless of your current directory, which may help. ([File::Spec](https://perldoc.pl/File::Spec) and [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) can help there)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Module::Metadata;
my $metadata = Module::Metadata->new_from_file('/path/to/File.pm');
my $package = $metadata->name;
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you can't, without parsing your files.
The right way is to use some standard perl module like https://perldoc.pl/Module::Metadata, but if you want to do it by yourself, with the following snippet you can extract all namespaces from inside each file (yes.. a file is just a container, so you may have more packages inside).

Quick and dirty way:

```
my $PACKAGES ;
my @files = ('lib/Foo.pm','lib/Bar.pm') ;
my $row ;
map {
    open PKGFILE , '<', $_ or die "Got error opening file $_: $!" ;
    while ( $row = <MODULE>){
        if ( $row =~ /\s*package\s+([\S]+)(.*?)[;{]/ ){
            # rx modified on Grinnz review
            push @{$PACKAGES->{ $_ }} , $1 ;
            # last ; # <== uncomment if you are sure each file 
                     #     contains only one package
        } ;
    }
    close PKGFILE ;
} @files ;
```

Assuming we have two files:

1) `lib/Foo.pm` (with 2 packages inside)

```
package Banana::Joe 0.003 ;

...code...

package Papaya::Frank 0.001 ;

...code...

1 ;
```

2) `lib/Bar.pm`

```
package Apple::Steve 0.013 ;

...code...

1 ;
```

`$PACKAGES` will be:

```
 {
   'lib/Bar.pm' => [
                     'Apple::Steve'
                   ],
   'lib/Foo.pm' => [
                     'Banana::Joe',
                     'Papaya::Frank'
                   ]
 };
```

Comment: `[0-9.]*` is not sufficient to parse the VERSION component of a package statement, and package statements can take BLOCKs containing the package contents since Perl 5.14. I strongly suggest not trying to reinvent this.

Comment: @Grinnz U're right, I fixed the regex.. it's still a fragile regex that not consider repetitions in one-line perl code nor other exotic cases. It's just for school, even if it can address the 99.99% of cases. BTW I think it's more educational to try to do things on their own, at least for personal culture, before using classes from others. Otherwise programming in perl will become like programming in Java, where the only thing to know is the name of the class to be instantiated without knowing how it works under the hood. But it's only my opionion, probably I'm wrong.

Comment: I think it's more effective to look at the source code of those modules suggested for your problem, than to try to reinvent all of the problems it already fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [PPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) for analysing (and rewriting) perl code. As I recall, a bit of a learning curve, but it worked fairly well. In your case, you really only need to find the `package <...>` statement from within the file. Anything more complex than that, such as someone using [autopackage](https://metacpan.org/pod/autopackage), and PPI probably wouldn't be able to help, either.